# Pyinstaller can't find a module? (error loading Python DLL)

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller

I compiled my program with pyinstaller, and it works fine on my computer, but whenever I ty to run it in another computer (with no python), I get the following error:

```
Error loading Python DLL  
'C:\Users\perez\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI28162\python310.dll'.
LoadLibrary: Cannot find specified module
```

What can I do? I'm not allowed to install python on the other computer

Comment: You have pyinstaller installed on another computer?

Comment: Is it possible that your target machine has a policy that forbids loading DLLs except from specified folders?

Comment: If that was the case, how could I change it? (it's a Windows 7 ultimate PC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it was not working because I compiled the script with pyinstaller having python 3.10, but Windows 7's maximum python version is 3.8

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it was because I was using the output in `build/main` instead of `dist/main` (`dist/main.exe` in case you used `--onefile`)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder where your Python.exe is located and run this Python.exe

Comment: But I used --onefile, so there is only one file